# How do I post using instagrapi?

Tags: python, authorization, instagram, photo, instagrapi

`Photo Upload failed with the following response: <Response [412]> raise PhotoNotUpload(response.text, response=response, **last_json) instagrapi.exceptions.PhotoNotUpload:{"debug_info":{"retriable":true,"type":"AuthorizationFailedError","message":"A temporary failure has occurred. Please try again."}}`

This is the error i receive when trying to upload photo to story happens with this code

```
session.photo_upload_to_story(path="5441.jpg",upload_id="upload_second",caption="lol")
```

and also this line too

```
session.photo_upload(path="5441.jpg",caption="First upload :)",location="Behind you",upload_id="upload_first_one",usertags=['messi', 'ksi','nike'])
```

Based off this I could guess it's not actually my fault? I can send messages with the API but can't send/post images or videos.

I can send over extra code if you need but they're not really relevant.